# Spring MVC : Getting date and time in specific format and persisting it

Tags: java, postgresql, date, spring-mvc

I am working on a Spring-MVC application in which I would like to save the date in a specific format(mentioned below). So in here, the user is not entering the date, but I am generating it in the backend. I would like to save in PostgreSQL in the same format too.
My problem is which format I use in database to persist it in the format mentioned below and how to generate the date in the format specified in Model. I hope my question was clear. If any doubts, please let me know.

Notes model :

```
import java.sql.Timestamp;

@Entity
@Table(name="groupnotes")
public class GroupNotes {

    @Id
    @Column(name="mnoteid")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,generator = "mnote_gen")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "mnote_gen",sequenceName = "mnote_seq")
    private int mnoticesid;

    @Column(name = "notedate")
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd.MM HH:MM") // I would like this format
    private Timestamp noteDate;
```

In the service layer, before this format was required, I was getting the date this way :

```
 notes.setNoteDate(new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()));
```

But this one gives it in its own format.

In PostgreSQL I am currently saving it in Timestamp without timezone. Any help would be nice. Thanks a lot.

Comment: A timestamp does not have a timezone.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis : That is just the option in PostgreSQL which I am using, so I wrote it that way. Also, in PostgreSQL, there is an option for TimeStamp with timezone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should really, really save your timestamps in ISO format with a time zone. And you should set your database server's time zone to UTC.

```
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column(columnDefinition = "timestamptz")
@DateTimeFormat("dd.MM HH:mm") //this is for display and parsing, not storage
private Date noteDate;
```

You can then display them with your `@DateTimeFormat` in a JSP:

```
<spring:eval expression="${noteDate}"/>
```

Also, your date format is probably not what you want.

You should also use snake_case for PostgreSQL identifiers.

Comment: This didn't work for me until I changed @DateTimeFormat to 
@DateTimeFormat(pattern="dd.MM HH:mm")
I'm using Spring 4.1.7